# Google Analytics Restrict view to show specific campaign

Tags: google-analytics

Hi I wanted to define a custom view in google analytics and restrict that view to only show data related to a specific campaign and nothing more, is it possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, create a new view and add a filter including only your campaign data (for example, by campaign name).

[image]